# How to install NancyFx on Ubuntu

Tags: nancy

I'm trying to learn how to use NancyFx with Mono in Ubuntu.

I've successfully built Nancy using the MonoRelease target in MonoDevelop (opening the solution in the IDE, selecting the MonoRelease build target, running Build).

I've created a new MonoDevelop solution in a separate directory called NancyTest. When I go add the references to the project it can't find them anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better answer then the super vague one already given. You can use Nuget to install the the items you need and then add them as references.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-Nginx-on-Ubuntu

The URL is a very nice example of how to get started with your first webpage. the nginx settings don't look super specialized, so you can probably use Apache if you wish. Since the items are written with mono and Nancy you can get away with using Jenkins CI, which is what turned me on to Nancy and mono, so I wouldn't have to install another server. Sorry this post is over a year old, but I came across it while looking for answers, and felt the answer currently given was poor and needed a better example for future users in the same search as me. So to answer your question, I'd bypass the build from source and just install using Nuget/powershell.